# binding osmdroid/osmbonusback into xamarin library

Tags: xamarin.android, osmdroid

At the moment I try to develope a simple maps Android application using Visual Studio 2012 and Xamarin.

For this reason I created a Binding Library, like it is desribed here:
[http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/java_integration_overview/binding_a_java_library_(.jar)/](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/java_integration_overview/binding_a_java_library_%28.jar%29/)

For my app it is essential to display markers and ballons with a short title text. I did a lot of research and found out, that I should use the osmbonuspack for this purpose. I tried to implement the "osmbonuspack_v4.5.jar" in my binding project as "Embedded Jar" but I think it's the wrong attempt.

Did someone managed it already to create a Xamaring Binding Library of the osmbonuspack? I would appreciate every attempt!